# ¿Como puedo imprimir arrays sin los corchetes y comillas en php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, html5

Estoy tratando de encontrar una manera de hacerlo pero no encuentro ninguna, he tratado de algunas formas pero me tira error, este es el código que uso para imprimir:

```
<?php
      $con = Conectar();
      $SQL = 'SELECT info FROM posts';
      $stmt = $con->prepare($SQL);
      $result = $stmt->execute();
      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $json = json_encode($rows);
      echo ($json);
    ?>
```

Lo que busco es poder imprimir con echo un array pero sin los corchetes y comillas como esto: [{"info":"información"}] y imprimir a esto: Información

Comment: Parece que pusiste un ejemplo de como **no** lo quieres. Si es así, podrías poder un ejemplo de cómo **sí** lo quieres.

Comment: @Marcos ya lo intenté y me sale este error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender como obtener la información que deseas, **primero necesitas saber** que es lo que devuelve cada función que estas utilizando.

Tenemos que [`$stmt->fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> **Devuelve un array** que contiene todas las filas del conjunto de resultados

Esto quiere decir que la variable **`$rows` es un arreglo**.
Luego podemos observar que estas usando el *"fetch style"* [`PDO::FETCH_OBJ`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> **devuelve un objeto** anónimo con nombres de propiedades que se corresponden a los nombres de las columnas devueltas en el conjunto de resultados.

Entonces `$rows` es un arreglo y **cada elemento dentro será un objeto**

---

#### Solución:

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, tu código podría verse así:

```
<?php
  $con = Conectar();
  $SQL = 'SELECT info FROM posts';
  $stmt = $con->prepare($SQL);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);// Un arreglo de objetos

  $post = $rows[0]; // El primer objeto en el arreglo
  echo $post->info; // La propiedad "info" del objeto

  // Lo que es igual a (pero mas difícil de ver):
  // echo $rows[0]->info;
?>
```

---

Referencias:

- [Arreglos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)
- [Objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema se debe a que haces un json_encode de tu array. Este método, automáticamente, tratará de convertir cualquier array con key y value en un json. Por lo tanto si pasas algo como: `json_encode([['foo' => 'bar']]);` este lo transformará en un `[{"foo":"bar"}]`. Trata de devolver tus datos sin transformarlos en un json usando esa función y mira si es el array que necesitas.

Comment: Lo solucioné con lo que comentó Marcos, pero intenté con esto, investigué como funciona pero no lo llegué a entender, me podrías pasar algún enlace para entenderlo a fondo? en la página oficial no llegué a entenderlo

Comment: pues si no te sirvió la documentación oficial, te dejo este par de links [enlace 1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiw7ubG3afvAhWhg-AKHZATAboQwqsBMAB6BAgFEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dxdzn8pUt7C4&usg=AOvVaw2Rpgi0FZQAwEGRWC3v1hBv) y [enlace 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiw7ubG3afvAhWhg-AKHZATAboQFjADegQIARAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.aulaformativa.com%2Fcomo-interpretar-formato-json-en-php%2F&usg=AOvVaw24vxwnpSXlvOU3lURdK21r)

Comment: Además, ya haces un fetch_obj, eso debería mostrarte los resultados en forma de objeto, por eso lo puedes ver de la manera en que Marcos te dice. Puedes intentar usar los métodos fetchAll o fetchColumn de PDO y te devolverá un array de arrays de php